# Can I add a formula to a google form response using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Apologies as I am a beginner to coding. I am interested in using Google Apps Script to automate the analysis of a Google Form response.

The [simple example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RgUaZQY_pdlWpC0NivVUO_yeJPzhPlgdV4ytHMvx9jk/edit?usp=sharing) I have is for the spreadsheet of responses for a form asking people:

1) how many players there were?
2) where they finished [1st, 2nd, etc,]

On submission of the form I want to run a script that calculates how may points they received and inserts this value in the next available column (column E in this example).

I have tried writing my first Apps Script to automate this process, but without success.

SAMPLE CODE:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses Master");
var players = e.values[2];
var place = e.values[3];
var positionPoints = e.values[4];
var positionPoints = (players - place + 1);

return positionPoints;
}
```

I know there are workarounds available by creating duplicate pages, but I was hoping someone might be able to advise me on how to code a solution in App Scripts, in the hope I might get a better understanding of the coding process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your appscript in the response collector spreadsheet itself instead of writing your code in form's script editor.

So, go to your response sheet and paste this code.

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses Master");
  var rowNo = sheet.getLastRow();
  var colNo = sheet.getLastColumn();
  sheet.getRange(rowNo, colNo).setValue("=(C"+rowNo+"-D"+rowNo+")+1");
}
```

Now, go to Resources -> Current project triggers. Click on add new and set these values in drop downs: myFunction - From Spreadsheet - On form submit.

And you are done. Whenever a new response is submitted, position points will be calculated automatically.

Here,
variable sheet gets your active spreadsheet for different sheet operations which you can perform.

rowNo and colNo as seen in the code, simply fetches the value of last row/column respectively of spreadsheet in which something is written.

And, to set formula in column 'E', you can use setValue. Hence, `"=(C"+rowNo+"-D"+rowNo+")+1"` will be converted to (C2-D2)+1 in case of second row and so on for next rows.

getRange is simply used to tell the script that write formula inside particular cell.